# Changing ngModel value programatically from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I wish to modify value of an `ngModel` variable from my controller. However it doesn't seem to be reflecting in views. I have seen few other questions on SO but none worked for me. I want a solution where I do not need to create a new directive for this. I have also tried to wrap the change in `$scope.$apply` without success.

Here is [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1WOLrV1uwNeY9q1UvVBr?p=preview) demonstrating the issue.

Here is code from plunkr

JavaScript Controller:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Attachment = "something"
  $scope.change = function () {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.Attachment = "otherthing";
      });
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <section class="content" ng-app="offer">
        <div>
            <button name="change" ng-click="change()" ng-model="Attachment">change</button>
            <!-- <input name="Attachment" type="file" class="file_up" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().change(this)" ng-model="Attachment" /> -->
            <span>{{Attachment}}</span>

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: add relevant code from plunker to your post also

Comment: you not need `$apply` for click event, remove it and all work

Comment: @DRobinson, nope, here not this case :-)

Comment: @DRobinson, add plunker with sample :-)

Comment: @Grundy it seems to work for this plunkr thanks !

Comment: @DRobinson what do you mean by "dot" ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal by "dot" it mean "." :-)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FLZPTUfCiLQFGe7BRzz2?p=preview

Comment: @DRobinson, but you remove $apply, and in comment you say only about "dot" ;-)

Comment: ^ You're correct. I get a bit too hasty, and quickly aggravated by the binding mistake (no, I will not call it a "decision"; intentional or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a best practice to bind to object properties instead of primitive types.
You are binding to a string which is a primitive type and is immutable.
You should also remove the `$apply` as it is not necessary since you are under the *angular* hood so it will perform the `$apply` automatically.

If you add your data as a property of an object you will not lose the reference anymore:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  //this has changed:
  $scope.data = {
    Attachment: "something"
  }

  $scope.change = function() {
    //and $apply was removed from here
    $scope.data.Attachment = "otherthing";
  }
});
```

and in the html you just need to change:

```
<span>{{data.Attachment}}</span>
```

**EDIT**: *although some other answers are correct, I thought you should see what's a best practice for binding. The updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OoNqTI?p=preview) here.*

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `ng-model` from the `button` and remove the `$scope.$apply` from the change handler:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lOyoTBxs0L0hMs20juLS?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Check this one may help you

```js
function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.Attachment = "something"
  $scope.change = function() {

    $scope.Attachment = "otherthing";

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
  <button name="change" ng-click="change()" ng-model="Attachment">change</button>

  <span>{{Attachment}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use $scope.$apply(). I made this change to the plunkr to get the view to update.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Attachment = "something"
  $scope.change = function () {
      $scope.Attachment = "other";
  }
});
```